# How to navigate to another page from a list item link?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to add a link column to my list which should take me to another page along with the current item id as query string. Is this possible with the native features of share point ? Or using some JSLink ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a calculated field.

```
="<a href='<url>?" & ID & "'>My link</a>"
```

But remember, it has to be a numeric output, or the html will be encoded

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. How to add a calculated field ? I can't find a Type named "Calculated" when I try to create a column in my Custom List. (I'm creating my custom list using Visual Studio)

Comment: that depends on how you add columns.. I usually use AddFieldAsXml - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms457586.aspx

Comment: but you also have the spfieldcalculated - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcalculated.aspx

Comment: @Burrhus do you mean create a new list column that contains this calculated field? Can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: @user5013 I have made a blogpost on it http://1001sp.blogspot.dk/2014/02/add-calculated-script-in-sharepoint-list.html